# Show dialog windows in Flash 8

Tags: flash, flash-8

I'm working with a very old version on Flash (Flash 8 Professional) and need to show popup windows similar to JQueryUI Dialog Boxes http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ . How can i get similar objects using this version of Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, you should create a MovieClip, then use `attachMovie`. Alternatively, maybe you could use that same boxes by calling a JavaScript function from the swf using `ExternalInterface` API. Furthermore, slightly different from your dialog, there was the built in Alert component (and personal solutions like this one: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=112190).